# How to create a user in SQLDeveloper with macOS?

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I currently have a mac and need to use Oracle SQLDeveloper for study purposes for university. Download SQLDeveloper on the official Oracle website, but unlike windows that have to install and enter a password for SYSTEM, when downloading SQLDeveloper it was an executable file that did not need a previous installation, the application works well, only I cannot use the user SYSTEM, since at no time enter a password, since I do not have a SYSTEM user, I cannot create a user and I cannot do my university work.

If any of you know how to find the SYSTEM password or how to create a user in any other way, I would be very grateful

Comment: SQLDeveloper is a client tool. It needs to have an Oracle server to connect to. Do you have an Oracle server to connect to? If you are just working locally, you'll need to install an Oracle server and create / enter the SYSTEM password for the server at installation time

Comment: Here's one way to install an Oracle server on Mac: https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-mac/

Comment: You need an Oracle server. You can setup free OCI account and create an Autonomous Datawarehouse, it will provide you a file using which you can connect to ADW from local SQL developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you'll be using Oracle for studying purposes, installing anything but its Express Edition (XE) is probably too much for you.

Unfortunately, you can't install XE directly on Mac OS. I don't have Mac so I can't speak from my own experience, but my colleague does and here's what he did: installed virtual machine under MS Windows and put Oracle XE onto it. He also has SQL Developer installed on the same virtual machine and uses everything in the same (Windows) environment.

I'd suggest you to do the same, unless there's a database available to you over the Internet (i.e. you can connect to a database DBA installed on a server that resides on the University); in that case, you'd need info about that database and establish connection once you're in the network (probably via VPN).

If you choose to use a virtual machine, there are walkthroughs available on the Internet; here's one of them: [How to Install Oracle on a Mac](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-mac/), see if it helps.

Or, see which preinstalled virtual machines Oracle offers for download, [here](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html#dbapp).